# Transform two NSImages on top of each other into a single NSImage without using `lockFocus`

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsimage

I have a large image and a smaller image, both in `Data` type which I transformed into `NSImage`. I want to put the smaller image on top of the large image, top-left aligned, in a new single `NSImage`.

Currently this code works, however both `lockFocus` and `unlockFocus` are deprecated. I don't think the documentation is clear enough for me to understand how I should rewrite it.

This is the working code:

```
func combineImages(image1: NSImage, image2: NSImage) -> NSImage {
    let size = NSMakeSize(max(image1.size.width, image2.size.width), max(image1.size.height, image2.size.height))
    let newImage = NSImage(size: size)
    
    newImage.lockFocus()
    
    image2.draw(at: NSPoint(x: 0, y: size.height - image2.size.height), from: NSZeroRect, operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
    image1.draw(at: NSZeroPoint, from: NSZeroRect, operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
    
    newImage.unlockFocus()

    return newImage
}
```

The deprecation method is:

> This method is incompatible with resolution-independent drawing and
> should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `init(size:flipped:drawingHandler:)` instead:

```
func combineImages(image1: NSImage, image2: NSImage) -> NSImage {
    let size = NSSize(width: max(image1.size.width, image2.size.width), height: max(image1.size.height, image2.size.height))
    let newImage = NSImage(size: size, flipped: false) { _ in
        let drawPointImage2 = NSPoint(x: 0, y: size.height - image2.size.height)
        image2.draw(at: drawPointImage2, from: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: image2.size), operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
        image1.draw(at: NSPoint.zero, from: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: image1.size), operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
        return true
    }
    
    return newImage
}
```

Using `rect` closure:

```
func combineImages(image1: NSImage, image2: NSImage) -> NSImage {
    let size = NSSize(width: max(image1.size.width, image2.size.width), height: max(image1.size.height, image2.size.height))
    let newImage = NSImage(size: size, flipped: false) { rect -> Bool in
        let drawPointImage2 = NSPoint(x: 0, y: size.height - image2.size.height)
        image2.draw(at: drawPointImage2, from: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: image2.size), operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
        image1.draw(at: NSPoint.zero, from: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: image1.size), operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
        return true
    }
    
    return newImage
}
```

↳ [init(size:flipped:drawingHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519860-init)

Comment: Can I safely ignore the `rect` closure parameter?

Comment: @J.Doe, Yes, it can be safely ignored; If you want to dynamically update your image or do other optimizations it might be useful.

Comment: Please add context that source images are copied and stay in memory. To get tiffrepresentation or archive can do but please do not keep this image in memory. The memory footprint for e.g. 5000x5000px image is disastrous